# stripos from an external file?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have this code now:

```
if ((stripos($text,'badword1') !== false) ||
   (stripos($text,'badword2') !== false))
    {
blablabla
}
```

It checks if in $text there is one of the bad word and it works well.

The problem is that I have several bad word so the code is pretty long.

Is it possible to put all the badwords in an external file and check it instead of put it all in the php?

Thanks.

EDIT AS ASKED, this is the full code. Is a Telegram bot in PHP:

```
if ((stripos($text,'badword') !== false))
    {
    $content = array(
        'chat_id' => $chat_id,
        'message_id' => $message_id,
        'text' => "messaggio cancellato",
'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
'disable_web_page_preview' => true
    );
    $telegram->sendMessage($content);
    $telegram->deleteMessage($content);
    }
```

I have tried one of the solution suggested but it does not work, like this:

```
$blacklist = "blacklist.txt";
$contents = file_get_contents($blacklist);
$lines = explode("\n", $contents);

if ((stripos($text,$lines) !== false))
    {
    $content = array(
        'chat_id' => $chat_id,
        'message_id' => $message_id,
        'text' => "messaggio cancellato",
'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
'disable_web_page_preview' => true
    );
    $telegram->sendMessage($content);
    $telegram->deleteMessage($content);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Why not try it out to see what happens?

Comment: I've been trying for a long times but i can't figure out how to make it. Example, I tried with

$filename = 'blacklist.txt';

if ((stripos(($text,file_get_contents($filename)) !== false))

but it does not work.

Comment: That depends on the structure of your file. Please add all attempts to your question by editing it. I would assume that you need to loop over all lines of that file

Comment: Depending on the amount of words, you can just [explode into an array and loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12665251/231316) or use something a little more efficient such as [SplFileObject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12665270/231316)

Comment: Look as `in_array()` load the bad word array from the file or make the file an includable php with the array set

Comment: something like [this](https://3v4l.org/YU2o7) might help solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you @berend your solution seems works! The only problem now is that if it found two or more badword it loops for every bad word found. Is it possible to break after the first condition? I try with "break" and "array_slice" but it just stop after the first row of the .txt

Answer (score 0):

In another file create array with bad words

```
// words.php
$words = ["word_1", "word_2", "word_3", "word_4"] // as many words as you need
```

Next, create your working file and call your words file:

```
// file.php
require "words.php";

function strposa($haystack, $needles=array(), $offset=0) {
    $chr = array();
    foreach($needles as $needle) {
            $res = strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset);
            if ($res !== false) $chr[$needle] = $res;
    }
    if(empty($chr)) return false;
    return min($chr);
}

$string = 'Some text that word_1 contain some bad words';

if (strposa($string, $words)) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Here I am using `strpos with array` with small function and code is looking very clean

Comment: Thanks, i think this will work but i am trying to make a .txt file to read from and not another PHP file with variable